# Why does the form input value is inconsistent when disabled?

Tags: angular, forms, input, storybook, formgroups

I am currently working on an Angular input component in StorybookJS. The problem that I am facing is that when I type a `value` (e.g., **hello**)  in the control panel in storybook js and click `disabled` to true, the input text gets disabled displaying the text "*hello*" and the text remains disabled as expected and returns to normal when `disabled` is false. And this is the correct behavior.

But, when I am actually typing in the input itself (e.g., **hello11**) and repeat the similar steps, when I click `disabled` to true, the value in the input will be changed and seen as "**hello**" instead of "**hello11**". So there is some inconsistency in the output of value when actually typing a value in the text input itself and disabling it.

Here is what I have:

In **input-test.component.html**:

```
<input 
  type="text"
  [(ngModel)]="value"
  [disabled]="disabled"
  (input)="updateValue($event)"
/>
```

In **input-test.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, Input, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-input-test',
  templateUrl: './input-test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input-test.component.css'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => InputTestComponent),
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class InputTestComponent implements ControlValueAccessor  {
  @Input() value: string = '';
  @Input() disabled: boolean = false;
  /**
   * @ignore
   */
  onChange: any = () => {};
  /**
   * @ignore
   */
  onTouch: any = () => {};

  writeValue(value: any): void {
    this.value = value;
  }
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouch = fn;
  }
  updateValue(event: Event): void {
    const newValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.value = newValue;
    this.onChange(this.value);
    this.onTouch(this.value);
  }
}
```

In **InputTest.stories.ts**:

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { InputTestComponent } from 'src/app/input-test/input-test.component';
import { Meta, StoryObj } from '@storybook/angular';
import { moduleMetadata } from '@storybook/angular';

const meta: Meta<InputTestComponent> = {
  component: InputTestComponent,
  title: 'Basic Components/InputTestComponent',
  tags: ['autodocs'],
  decorators: [
    moduleMetadata({
      declarations: [InputTestComponent],
      imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
    }),
  ],
  args: {},
  render: (args: InputTestComponent) => ({
    props: {
      ...args,
    },
  }),
  argTypes: {},
};
export default meta;

type Story = StoryObj<InputTestComponent>;

const createFormGroup = (value: string, disabled: boolean) => {
  const fb = new FormBuilder();
  return fb.group({
    name: [{value: value, disabled: disabled}],
  });
};

export const Default: Story = {
  args: {
    value: 'default',
    disabled: false,
  },
  render: (args) => ({
    props: {
      ...args,
      form: createFormGroup(args.value, args.disabled),
    },
    template: `
        <form [formGroup]="form">
          <app-input-test formControlName="name" [(ngModel)]="value" [disabled]="disabled"></app-input-test>  
        </form>
        <div>Name: {{ form.get('name').value }}</div>
      `,
  }),
};
```

Can someone help me with this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. `value` is **NOT** an `@Input` else a simple variable.
2. You needn't change the variable `this.value` in your function
   `updateValue`
3. `disabled`is **NOT** an `@Input`
4. You need implements the method [`[setDisabledState]`](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor)